# Get key from an array in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

If I have an array that looks like this:

```
$my_array = array(2) { ["mykey"]=> int(2) ["mysecondkey"]=> int(3) }
```

How can I get to the key value of the first element?.

So far I know I can do `$my_array[0]`, but how do I get to the first key? I want to avoid doing foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you are asking for the key name or the value assigned to that key name.

Answer (score 1):

This is associative array (string keys). Use name of key directly:

```
$my_array["mykey"];
```

Read [more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) 
To extract keys use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$my_array = array(2) { ["mykey"]=> int(2) ["mysecondkey"]=> int(3) }
$keys = array_keys($my_array); //0 => "mykey", 1 => "mysecondkey"
```

Comment: I want to get the key name of the first element, not the value of the first element.

Comment: Denis Ermolin, I want to voiad using array_keys. I am in smarty and I just want to fetch that key from $my_array[0]

Comment: Why you dont want to modify $my_array? Make array_keys and pass to smarty

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get a list of your array's keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
echo $keys[0]; // outputs "mykey"
```

If you want to do this in Smarty, you can use the following code to output the array's first key:

```
{foreach from=$my_array key=my_key item=i name=my_array}
  {if $smarty.foreach.my_array.first}{$my_key}{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Carsten, I get an array like the one I show in smarty and I need to access directly from the template.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Okay, I added an example on how to do it in a smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$_val){
    echo $key;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_keys() will get all the keys in an array, while this will get the first key without iterating all the others and ignoring the rest of the array.

It is a fake loop as the break will exit at the first iteration, so you are not actually doing a real foreach for all the values.

```
foreach($my_array as $firstKey=>$unused) {
    break;
}
echo($firstKey);
```

If you need a function, you may use this:

```
function first_key($arr) {
    foreach($my_array as $firstKey=>$unused) {
        return $firstKey;
    }
}
```

Again the function returns at the first iteration, so you are not doing a "real" foreach on all the elements.